# jQuery timer, ajax, and "nice time"

Tags: jquery, time, timer, unix-timestamp

So for this is what I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div p").load("/update/temp.php");

    function addOne() {
        var number = parseInt($("#div p").html());
        return number + 1;
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#div p").text(addOne());
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#geupdate p").load("/update/temp.php");
    }, 10000);
});
```

So this grabs a a UNIX timestamp from temp.php and puts into into #div p, and then adds 1 to it every second, and then every 10 seconds it will check the original file to keep it up to speed.

My problem is that I need to format this UNIX timestamp into a format such as "1 day 3 hours 56 minutes and 3 seconds ago", while also doing all the incrementation and ajax calls.
I'm not very experienced with jquery/javascript, so I might be missing something basic.

Comment: Maybe this jQuery plugin is what you want? http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/ or at least be a template that you can use to make it display what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.datejs.com/ does everything you could possibly want to do with dates in javascript. The first available download is out of date, but the SVN version is fine.